# Voice speed control in Amazon Polly?

Tags: java, text-to-speech, amazon-polly

I have implemented this Java program to do TTS with Polly: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/examples-java.html

I am using the Dutch male voice which is good and natural, but I find it a bit too fast. I see in the Polly docs that the voice speed can be controlled using something like this in SSML as shown on this page: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/ssml-synthesize-speech-cli.html

```
aws polly synthesize-speech \
--text-type ssml \
--text '<speak><prosody rate="x-slow">Hello world</prosody></speak>' \
--output-format mp3 \
--voice-id Joanna \
speech.mp3
```

But how do I incorporate that into my Java? I tried this (with format adjustment for Windows):

```
text = "\<speak><prosody rate='x-slow'>" + text + "</prosody></speak> ^";
PollyDemo helloWorld = new PollyDemo(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
InputStream speechStream = helloWorld.synthesize(text, OutputFormat.Mp3);
```

But I am groping in the dark. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out. First, you must add the parameter ".withTextType(TextType.Ssml)" to your SynthesizeSpeechRequest. Then you can use {text = "\<speak><prosody rate='x-slow'>" + text + "</prosody></speak>";} to convert your text to SSML. Other rates that you can use are shown in the SSML specifications here: https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/

Comment: You can also specifiy the rate in percentage for the perfect rate :) `<prosody rate='80%'>`